# Thread Executing sometimes doubled

Tags: java, multithreading, windows-server-2003

I have an old application that has a robot thread that executes everyday. I have the source for the robot, but I don't know how this tread is started. And there's a log, witch includes a line in a database, that sometimes includes 2 identical lines, proving that  the process is executing doubled.

we use Windows Server 2003

```
public void run()
{
while (true)
{
  starter();
  try {
    Thread.sleep(10800000L);
  }
  catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException)
  {
  }
}
}
```

I need to keep it from executing more than once.

I'm new to treads, don't really get the works of a thread right yet...

thank you all in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really provide a lot of information, but here are a few guesses:

- Could the entire process be launched twice?
- If the thread is running twice, showing the thread run function won't help. You'll have to find the code that creates the thread.
- Log something in the catch block. Maybe a sleep call gets interrupted immediately and this is why `starter()` is called twice at almost the same time.

Comment: I think the answer is far easier than that, but I might be wrong, he never mentioned that the `starter()` is called twice at almost at the same time. Could it be that he just needs to increase the amount of sleep time?

Comment: i could not find the code starting the process. that's Why I can't correct the problem. I don't know if it's executing directly from apache ou from the server. we don't have any documentation about this, and no one that implemented the software still works in the company.

Comment: @CarlosJunior Shouldn't it be possible to search the code base for all uses of the class containing this code? That can't yield that many results, can it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void run()
{
      int delay = 86400000; //milliseconds
      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              starter();
          }
      };
      new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
}
```

Or...

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class DailyTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Or if you use a logger like log4j you can insert logger code here.
        System.out.println("Start:" + new Date());
        starter();
        System.out.println("End:" + new Date());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        TimerTask tt= new DailyTask();
        // running timer task as daemon thread
        Timer t = new Timer(true);
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 86400000);
        System.out.println("DailyTask started:" + new Date());
    }

}
```

This should run starter() once every 24 hours.

Comment: Another option is to look into using something like the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/quick-start) but its a bit more work to setup but may be more reliable.

Comment: There's a way I can prevent it to run multiple stances? like using an flag or something (Ex. AtomicBoolean).

Comment: you can use the java synchronized keyword on the run method to lock the method from other threads. `public synchronized void run()`